# cmd.exe /k (echo %1 & echo %~n1) doesnt output as expected when put in registry command key

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, contextmenu

```
cmd.exe /k (echo "%1" & echo "%~n1")
```

I'm expecting this output

```
"X:\Desktop\output\Birthday Party.mp4"
"Birthday Party"
```

But this is what I'm getting

```
"X:\Desktop\output\Birthday Party.mp4"
"%~n1"
```

I know how to get the result by using a bat file but I want to exclusively use registry.

Comment: %1 isn't here a batch parameter it's a registry parameter, therefore the batch modifiers doesn't work

Comment: I dont know if its a batch parameter but the same code works fine when copied into a batch file...

Comment: if i use `set myvariable="%1" & echo %myvariable%` then output is `myvariable`again this works fine when copied into a bat file

Comment: The internal equivalent to `ShellExecuteEx` ends up calling `CreateProcess` with the command line `cmd.exe /k (echo "X:\Desktop\output\Birthday Party.mp4" & echo "%~n1")`. Even if CMD saw the `"%1"` literally, AFAIK it doesn't support command-line arguments like that for `/c` or `/k` commands, i.e. something like `cmd /k "command "%1" "%2"" arg1 arg2` isn't supported. Use a batch script for that, e.g. `"Path\To\Script.bat" "%1"`.

Answer (score 2):

The shell parser does not support the same parameter options as batch files.

You have to use batch code to extract the filename:

```
cmd /k echo.%1&for %%A in ("%1") do @echo.%%~nA
```

The full list of supported shell parameters is not actually officially documented anywhere, Microsoft only documents the basic ones like %1 but you can see most of them [listed here](https://superuser.com/questions/136838/which-special-variables-are-available-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-context/473602) by a Windows developer.